# Callout is out of frame

Tags: plotting, labeling

In the documentation of [`Callout`](https://wolfram.com/xid/0b8cq2wjee-np8bim), there is an example,

```
Table[ListPlot[Table[Callout[Fibonacci[n], Fibonacci[n], p], {n, 10}],
   Frame -> True], {p, {Above, Below, Before, After}}]
```

the result of the documentation is

[image]

every callout is precisely inside Frame.

However, on my computer, I got Callouts out of frame all over the place.

[image]

Version 12.2 and 13.1 give same result, what is wrong? How to fix it without manually tweaking like `PlotRangePadding`?

Comment: I see that in V 13.1 also. another workaround: just add `Imagesize`. Like this `data = Table[Callout[Fibonacci[n], Fibonacci[n], p], {n, 10}];
Table[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200],
 {p, {Above, Below, Before, After}}]` here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LfBv.png)  there might be better worksrounds. This looks like a bug?

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much for workaround. That is a quite unexpected workaround, and what is wrong with the right part the frame after adding `ImageSize`? they looks like dashed lines.

Comment: THis is easy to fix. Just add `ImagePadding`. Here is an update `data=Table[Callout[Fibonacci[n],Fibonacci[n],p],{n,10}];
Table[ListPlot[data,Frame->True,ImageSize->200,ImagePadding->10],
{p,{Above,Below,Before,After}}]` screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soBpA.png)  note that `ImagePadding` alone does not do the trick.

Comment: @Nasser Awesome!